# JsonPath expression not applying the condition

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm recieving multiple Events (following JSON) from a Queue and I don't want to take all of them, only the events with Sales Organization="180C":

```
{
    "eventID": "string",
    "eventType": "string",
    "eventDate": "2024-03-15T18:21:24Z",
    "source": "string",
    "dataKey": "string",
    "dataChange": {
        "KEY": []
    },
    "dataScope": {
        "dataObject": "string",
        "KEY": [
            {
                "scope": "scope1",
                "value": "scope2"
            },
            {
                "scope": "scope2",
                "value": "scope3"
            },
            {
                "scope": "Sales Organization",
                "value": "190B" 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I used this filter but not working as intended :

```
$.[?($.dataScope.KEY[?(@.scope=='Sales Organization' && @.value=='190B')])]
```

When I try this filter alone : $.dataScope.KEY[?(@.scope=='Sales Organization' && @.value=='190B')]
I get an empty array [] when the condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

UDPATE:

1. When using the brackets syntax `[]`, don't use a dot `.`.  So you'll start with `$[`, not `$.[`.
2. When iterating over items, you'll need to use the `@` to start paths in filters.  `@` indicates the current item root. `$` indicates the document root.

So, instead of starting your path with `$.[?($.dataScope`, start with `$[?(@.dataScope`.

```
$[?(@.dataScope.KEY[?(@.scope=='Sales Organization' && @.value=='190B')])]
```

---

*Previous answer, not knowing that the posted event was one in an array of events.*

> `$.[?($.dataScope`

What is this for? Why the extra bit on the front?

You have the right path, it's just buried in this extra filter for some reason.
Just use

```
$.dataScope.KEY[?(@.scope=='Sales Organization' && @.value=='190B')]
```

(also, `$.[]` with a dot is invalid.  Omit the dot when using brackets: `$[]`.)

You can test this at https://json-everything.net/json-path, which implements the new IETF JSON Path specification [RFC 9535](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9535.html).

---

**EDIT**

The output for this (from my playground) is

```json
[
  {
    "Value": {
      "scope": "Sales Organization",
      "value": "190B"
    },
    "Location": "$['dataScope']['KEY'][2]"
  }
]
```

Comment: $.dataScope.KEY[?(@.scope=='Sales Organization' && @.value=='190B')]
returns only the KEY which statisfies the condition. I want the result to be the entire input JSON.

Comment: "I want the result to be the entire input JSON"  I don't understand this.  Can you edit your question with the JSON you want to get back?  If you want the entire JSON, why are you filtering?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm recieving multiple Event JSONs from a Queue and I don't want to take all of them, only the events with Sales Organization="180C"

Comment: answer updated.  You're close.